# Load and parse an yaml file from S3, using a nodejs AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, yaml

I have an AWS lambda that has to...

- read from S3 an yaml file,
- transform the content into an object,
- than do some wonderful staff with it.

I can handle the last point, but I do not know how to read and parse that yaml file.

Here is the code I need to complete:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const YAML = require('js-yaml');

const S3 = new AWS.S3();

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const [record] = event.Records;
  const bucket = record.s3.bucket.name;
  const { key } = record.s3.object;

  const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key };
  console.log(params);

  S3.getObject(params).promise()
    .then((x) => {

      // ?????????????????????????????????????????
      // HOW TO DO SOME MAGIC AND GET THE OBJECT ?

    })
    .then((fileContentObject) => {
      // DO SOME WONDERFUL STAFF (example: console.log :) )
      console.log(JSON.stringify(fileContentObject))
    })
    .then(() => callback)
    .catch(callback);
};
```

Feel free to suggest another approach to read and parse the yaml file. I prefer a Promise approach if possible.

Comment: What did you try before posting here?  Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: I do not see how to bind the `S3.getObject(params)` with the `js-yaml`. Since it is the first time I use `js-yaml` I do not know what input to give to `YAML.parse()` or `YAML.read()`? All I ask is an example of code supposed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem. "It was easy", of course!

Here is the code in lambda:

```
S3.getObject(params).promise()
  .then((configYaml) => {
    // Get the content of the file as a string
    // It works on any text file, should your config is in another format
    const data = configYaml.Body.toString('utf-8');
    console.log(data);

    // Parse the string, which is a yaml in this case
    // Please note that `YAML.parse()` is deprecated
    return YAML.load(data);
  })
  .then((config) => {
    // Do some wonderful staff with the config object
    console.log(`• Config: ${JSON.stringify(config)}`);
    return null;
  })
  .then(callback)
  .catch(callback);
```

All I was asking for is: `YAML.load(configYaml.Body.toString('utf-8'))`.